# Algorithm C# unity chess game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, chess

I'm making a 2D chess game using Unity.

I'm writing the code that tells if the piece can move to this position or not.

Here is the explanations about how I did it:

- There is a "wallpaper" representing the board.
- On each square of the "wallpaper", I put an other square with desactivated mesh renderer.
- When the player select a square, if there is a piece on this position, I activate the mesh renderers of all squares where the piece can go.
- All squares are stored in a simple array I use to determine possible positions.

With pawns, no problem, it works perfectly, but with rooks or knights, the mouvement is more complicated and I have issues doing this.

here I will work with knights.

When it is in the center of the board, no problem: http://prntscr.com/crcogo

But when I'm on a side of the board, well, check by yourself: http://prntscr.com/crcozu

Here is the code:

```
case "White_Knight(Clone)_0":
                int Index_Knight_1 = Array.IndexOf(Board, Square_Selected);
                // Les cases en +
                if (Index_Knight_1 + 6 <= 64 )
                {
                    Board[Index_Knight_1 + 6].GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = true;
                }
                if (Index_Knight_1 + 10 <= 64)
                {
                    Board[Index_Knight_1 + 10].GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = true;
                }
                if (Index_Knight_1 + 15 <= 64)
                {
                    Board[Index_Knight_1 + 15].GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = true;
                }
                if (Index_Knight_1 + 17 <= 64)
                {
                    Board[Index_Knight_1 + 17].GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = true;
                }
                // les cases en -
                if (Index_Knight_1 - 6 >= 0)
                {
                    Board[Index_Knight_1 - 6].GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = true;
                }
                if (Index_Knight_1 - 10 >= 0)
                {
                    Board[Index_Knight_1 - 10].GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = true;
                }
                if (Index_Knight_1 - 15 >= 0)
                {
                    Board[Index_Knight_1 - 15].GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = true;
                }
                if (Index_Knight_1 - 17 >= 0)
                {
                    Board[Index_Knight_1 - 17].GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = true;
                }
```

I thnik I don't use the correct way to do this, but I would like to script it myself without taking pieces of code there or there.

In this case, I thought about using multiples of eight, but I'm stuck here :D

Could someone give me a piece of an advice?

Thanks!

Ho, I know it should not be "64" in the conditions, but 63, just saw it.

Comment: why not using 2d coordinates and then convert back and forth?

Comment: I switched from a one dimensional to a rwo dimensional array, semmed way easier. But I can't find a way to find in the array the position of a specific element (I'm searching objets)

Comment: 2D array is definitely the way to go: Board[Index_Knight_X + 2, Index_Knight_Y - 1].GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = true; You'll need to check the limits of the array to ensure Index_Knight_X + 2 or Index_Knight_Y - 1] is not a negative

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm doing, but is there a way to use the equivalent of array.IndexOf() on a 2D array?

Comment: add two public members (x,y) for board sqaure and set them in unity editor

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Question solved. I wanted a way to deal with position in an array, found it with a 2D array, thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Absinte - I am working on a similar game that uses a 7x7 board.  It is much easier to work with a 2 dimension array.  When one of my pieces is selected, I loop through a list of the moves it COULD make - these are +/- offsets assuming that the piece is in the center.  For a pawn, the x,y offsets would be:
0,+1;0,+2(first move only),+1,+1,-1,+1 ( the last two are if capturing ).

I apply each of these to the current x,y location of the piece and if both the x and y are within 0 and 6, then I will display it as a possible location to which the piece could move.